# Android Screencast fails (please help a new Android Dev)

Tags: java, android, security, certificate, signing

I'm setting up new AndroidDevEnvironment and I'm stuck on this error while trying to open Android Screencast which allows you to use *your android device* via PC via keyboard and mouse and display mirroring and more

> Because of rep limits (need at least 10 to post images) [I posted details here](http://justpaste.it/er2i)

(Yes, I lowered the security to the lowest setting (which is medium in Java Settings) and at least the .jnlp **now goes past** the `Your security settings have blocked a local application from running message`)

This seems like a simple error to fix but Im a late on schedule noob at Java that google failed to help

Comment: If this can't be solved D-: then is there an alternative to this Android Screencast?

Comment: Have you enabled the debugging and that on your android device?

Comment: @Howlin yes i have the device id is shown  when i input `adb devices` in terminal

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding this two links to to the Exception Site List.

http://code.google.com

http://androidscreencast.googlecode.com

[image: screenshot]

It's possible to run Java Control Panel via a command:

```
$ javaws -viewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your java security settings in your operation system. This happen because android screencast not permission for made executed.

Comment: @ ingeyesid thanks very much for your answer.My java security settings areat the lowest possible (there is no lower than middle option) how else can i lower them?

Comment: And your firewall ? Java for default not start applications from "unknown" developer .try downloading again the executable.

Comment: thanks very much again.I downloaded again and checked to see the security is set to lowest.I didnt install any firewall and I installed Lubuntu 14.04 over Windows (I didnt have any firewall on Win either) just to see if this problem will be solved